# Use Unicode font as @font-face

Tags: css, unicode, font-face

In my webpage css file, I used a "Bangla" (Bangladeshi) unicode font - "SolaimanLipi" as `font-face`;
I am sure the location is correct and font name is renamed as "sol.ttf". I linked the font like this and used many place in my page as `font-family:bodyf`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:bodyf;
    src: url("../font/sol.ttf");
    format("opentype");
}
```

**It's working well in my local server. But It's not working after hosting at hosting server.**

What's wrong in my code or what did I miss?
Thank you.

Comment: Link us to your hosting server where you're having trouble.

Comment: http://www.shebamcsl.com

Comment: On which browser(s) does this happen? On Firefox for example, the Solaiman Lipi font *is* used when I view shebamcsl.com.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, specifying the **charset** on the page with the metatag `charset` solve the problem.

So, try to write in your `<head>` tag (i think utf-8 might work for you):

```
<meta charset='YOUR_SET'>
```

Or, if you are in page before html5, you can use the long version:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=YOUR_SET'>
```

More info on `charset` metatag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp).

Another possibility is a problem with the **hosting relative paths**. Try to enter the absolute path to the font file. Write so in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:bodyf;
    src: url("http://www.shebamcsl.com/.../font/sol.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

Other possibility concerns the **compatibility**. Read [this](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/) article to learn more about the specifics about each browser. A skeleton of a complete `@font-face` is the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bodyf';
    src: url('../font/sol.eot');
    src: local('body f'),
         url('../font/sol.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/sol.svg#font') format('svg'); 
}
```

Comment: I already have it

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/pdStyle.css"></link>
</head>

Comment: Can you link your website? Of course, is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and not <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" /> like you write now, right?

Comment: You maybe try to put, instead of relative path, the absolute path to the font file. So, read the edit answer.